# Komodo Edit - code-completion for Django?

Tags: python, django, ide, code-completion, komodo

I've been using Komodo Edit for a small project in Django.

The code completion features seem to work pretty well for standard python modules, however, it doesn't know anything about Django modules.   Is there any way to configure Komodo Edit to use Django modules for autocomplete as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By sure Django is on your python path and Komodo should pick it up. Alternatively you can add the location of Django to where Komodo looks for its autocomplete.

Comment: It was already on my python path (could import django stuff via plain old python shell), however,komodo didn't know about it.  Manually adding the dist-packages folder fixes it though.

Comment: @TM - are you sure you have added the same Python (`which python` in shell) in Komodo's preferences as well? Komodo internally uses that Python's `sys.path` (which would obviously include `dist-packages`) as well.

Answer (score 8):

> o to Edit > Preferences. Expand the
>   "Languages" group by clicking the  [+]
>   symbol. Click "Python". Click the
>   little "Add..." button under 
>   "Additional Python Import
>   Directories". Add the directory ABOVE
>   your  project and you should have
>   intellisense enabled.

This has always worked for me for both Django and my individual projects.

Comment: This allows me to see code completion for my own project files, but still no dice for django stuff.

Comment: Ya, you have to do it for Django *as well as* your project, but it looks like you got it figured out.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm. It's installed by default so my answer probably isn't the right solution. :-)

But here goes...

You can install a Django extension in Komodo edit. I haven't tested it myself but you can test it.

> Tools -> Add-ons -> Extensions

It's name is "Django Language".

Check if it works.

Comment: This is for the Django Template Language