# Komodo Code Completion for Django

Tags: django, autocomplete, komodo

Sorry to repeat old questions, but I didn't quite understand the answer.

The question was: How to enable auto-complete in Komodo Edit 5.2 for Django 
[Komodo Edit - code-completion for Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424392/komodo-edit-code-completion-for-django)

"It was already on my python path (could import django stuff via plain old python shell), however,komodo didn't know about it. **Manually adding the dist-packages folder fixes it though**"

In particular I don't understand the part in bold.

Can you give me a simple step by step recipe for that, please?

Using OSX Snow Leopard.

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `File -> Preferences -> Languages -> Python`. There you have the field *Additional Python Import Directories* where you can add the Django folder (actually **the folder that contains** the Django folder).

Comment: That's where I was going wrong! I was trying to add the Django folder itself. Thank you!!